# Проблема с exe pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller

С помощью pyinstaller сделал exeшник, когда запускаю, открывается консоль и сразу закрывается.
Попробовал запустить его через командную строку, там выдаёт ошибку https://i.stack.imgur.com/ixbUC.jpg как пофиксить?

Comment: В коде было что то с названием bs4? И пожалуйста скидывайте traceback-и в текстовом виде.

Comment: да, был импорт библиотеки bs4

Comment: попробуйте использовать auto py to exe

Comment: абсолютно тоже самое